# Can this function be a new test for primality?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, primality-test

The following function returns always 0 only if a number is not prime.

$$
H(x)=\prod_{i=2}^{x-1}\left\{\left[\sum_{k=1}^{x/i}(-i)\right]+x\right\}
$$

what do you think?

Bye!

Comment: I think you should have read [MathJax help](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/tex-latex-mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on the and have typeset the formula yourself. Then you should think about what the formula does.

Comment: I think that it is nothing more than a computer program. You may as well iterate all numbers in the range $[2,x-1]$ and check if $x$ is divisible by any of them (which is what this formula essentially does). One can easily establish such formula. For example, consider $$F_n=\left\lfloor\frac{\left(\sum\limits_{k=2}^{n-1}\left\lceil\frac{{n}\bmod{k}}{n}\right\rceil\right)+2\cdot\left\lceil\frac{n-1}{n}\right\rceil}{n}\right   \rfloor$$ The real challenge is to establish a prime-formula which is not "computationally worthless".

Comment: ah ok!  you're right and thank you :)

I thought could be useful because there are not computer programming statements like "if" (If mod is zero or if this number is divisible by x) into this function. When into the product there is a zero, does not make sense continue and so, the number is not prime.

But yes this function seems contain two "while" loops :)

Comment: You might want to take a look at http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeFormulas.html and http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FRACTRAN.html

Comment: @LuckySideburn "while" loops are hidden "if" statements.

Answer (score 6):

Your formula is essentially a computer program which iterates all integers in the range $[2,x−1]$.

One can easily establish such formula, for example:

$$F_n=\left\lfloor\frac{\left(\sum\limits_{k=2}^{n-1}\left\lceil\frac{{n}\bmod{k}}{n}\right\rceil\right)+2\cdot\left\lceil\frac{n-1}{n}\right\rceil}{n}\right\rfloor$$

The real challenge is to establish a formula which is not "computationally worthless".

Answer (score 1):

Let us take the formula apart slowly.

First we have a product over all the possible divisors of $x$. The product will be zero if just one factor is zero, so claiming that $H(x)$ is 0 only if $x$ is not prime, amounts to claiming that if $x$ is composite, one of the factors will be zero - my guess is that we'll get a zero if $i$ is a factor of $x$.

Then let us look at the sum
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{x/i}(-i)
$$

$i$ is a constant in the sum, so this is
$$
-i\left\lfloor\frac{x}{i}\right\rfloor
$$
if $i$ is a divisor of $x$ is this is $-x$, else it will be smaller. So if $i$ is a divisor of $x$ we get zero when adding $x$, if it isn't we get some positive number. So I guessed right.

---

Following up on the comments, there are plenty of ways to write formulas without "computer programming statements" that give a result that shows if a number is prime, but when it comes to primality testing formulas aren't worth much, it's the computational complexity it depends on, and your formula is not good in that regard, it involves a lot of calculations that are not be needed.

Comment: Yes Henrik, this is the behavior of my function.. but it seems a computer program :)